# AWS SNS not sending Subscription Confirmation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have setup AWS SNS setup with a topic say 'A'. I'm doing a subscribe to this SNS topic using Http (tried both manually using AWS console online and using Java Code). All I get is 'pending confirmation' in both cases. However SNS does not send the initial 'SubscriptionConfirmation' to the provided Url.

Note that my endpoint is ready to receive http POST notification. When I manually do a POST from my side I see my servlet processing those Json I send. For some reason I receive nothing from AWS SNS.

Note that my http end point that I used for subscribe is public facing so SNS should have no issue reaching it.

Any inputs is appreciated.

Here is my subscribe function.

```
public String subscribe(String arn,String url) {

    if(arn == null || arn.isEmpty())
        arn = topicArn;
    SubscribeRequest subRequest = new SubscribeRequest(arn,"http",url);
    SubscribeResult  result = snsClient.subscribe(subRequest);
    //get request id for SubscribeRequest from SNS metadata
    if(result != null){
        LOGGER.info("SubscribeResult - " + result.toString());
    }
    LOGGER.info("SubscribeRequest - " + snsClient.getCachedResponseMetadata(subRequest));
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Note that my http endpoint is an aws EC2 instance is publicly reachable.

Comment: strange thing is that I can't even receive the subscription confirmation even if I try to subscribe manually using aws console UI. I get the same result which is 'pending confirmation'

Comment: What do the security group rules look like on the EC2 instance? Is port 80 wide open with no restrictions? Is the URL you are sending to SNS something that you can successfully hit with your web browser?

Comment: The post 80 is wide open from outside. Yes I can. In fact when I do a Post using a REST client , my endpoint is able to receive it and process the message.

Comment: what is the result you get back?

Comment: For my REST POST from I receive the String return in my endpoint processing. I defined a AWS SQS queue and when I subscribe to my SNS Topic my SQS is able to receive the message notifications by poll. Is it a must I should use SQS with SNS ?. Can I just use SNS to publish and subscribe ?.

Comment: Ok I created a SQS and subscribed to my SNS topic. My SQS is able to read the data from topic. I wrote code to read the SQS by polling . My question is why is my SQS able to read polling where as I'm not getting notifications. But that's not the point. Why should I poll ?. The whole point of SNS is it will notify the subscribers when there is data available in the topic. Basically my SNS is not send the initial subscription confirmation to the subscriber. My subscriber is public facing and ready to receive initial message.. Any one have any clue.

Answer (score 2):

You are always going to get "pending confirmation" as the response for the subscriptionArn.   The confirmation process is asynchronously as a separate process.  To make this even more confusing if you call to get a list of current subscriptions they will show an slightly different subscriptionArn of "PendingConfirmation" so you can not even match it later.

As far as being able to connect, I would try hitting an end point outside of AWS first.   By default most AWS elements are very locked down and can not even connect to each other, so there is likely a security setting somewhere that needs to be changed to let SNS connect to your EC2.  Which would be why you can connect to the EC2 outside of AWS, but your SNS service can not.

Also check to make sure the SNS and EC2 you are using are in the same region.   It is a common cause of connection issues.

If you are using a host name to connect I would try using the direct IP to see if it gets through.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot, you should turn on the "Delivery status" reports in topic actions - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-msg-status.html. Then you will see why the confirmation message failed to be sent from AWS side.

On your EC2 instance side, on network level you must make sure that the port you are listening on is open from outside. There are several things: both making sure the port is open in firewall (Security groups settings), and making sure that the IP is reachable (i.e., make sure your VPC where the machine is located is publicly visible).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, the region was the problem.

Make sure the **SNS, CloudWatch and EC2** are in the **same region**.

Answer (score 0):

For me disabling encryption on the topic allowed the emails to finally be delivered, albeit to the spam folder.